# What does yum actually do?

Tags: sudo, command-line, yum

I've seen `yum` used as a command for Cento OS Red Hat Linux platform. But, I tried with `sudo` too and it works.

So, I want to know what `yum` actually does.

Comment: You need to ask this on a redhat forum ;) Yum is not part of debian or ubuntu.

Comment: I didn't know it. That's why I asked it here, isn't it? In next time I will ask it on Red Hat forum. But, I am running Ubuntu only. Not Red Hat. Just wanted to know for curiosity

Comment: The question is about Red Hat Linux (and family), thus not about Ubuntu. You might want to ask it on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Actually I didn't knew that this topic is about Red Hat Linux. But, I thought I can ask here about anything Linux. That's the reason!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It allows you to install various packages whilst installing all the dependencies that it requires. It does all the heavy lifting like other package managers such as apt-get.

http://yum.baseurl.org/

> Yum is an automatic updater and package installer/remover for rpm
>   systems. It automatically computes dependencies and figures out what
>   things should occur to install packages. It makes it easier to
>   maintain groups of machines without having to manually update each one
>   using rpm. Yum has a plugin interface for adding simple features. Yum
>   can also be used from other python programs via its module inteface.

Comment: Thank you for your details explaination to me. Would it work on Ubuntu too then?

Comment: I have never tried it but you could give it a shot with a couple of non-important packages, follow the provided URL and it should lead to some more information on the matter. If this proved helpful please accept the answer.